# NetConnection addHeader not working?

Tags: php, flash, actionscript, http-headers, netconnection

I am using an open source flash player to play video files. Now the twist is that the server that hosts the files checks the Referer in the header before serving the files, so I need a way to forge these headers.

I'm on my own server, where I try setting the video file to my PHP script:

```
$headers =  getallheaders();
$string = '';
foreach($headers as $key=>$val){
  $string .= $key . ': ' . $val . "\n";
}
```

And I mail myself the string and then serve the video file. For some reason, I just cannot forge or even add any extra headers to the request:

```
    nc = new NetConnection();
    nc.addHeader('Referer', true, 'http://google.com');
    nc.addHeader('Test', true, 'http://google.com');
```

I am using the opensource and light-weight flash player: 
http://gokercebeci.com/dev/download/f4player